# How to store javascript variable value in jsp string?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Eg : I have 
       var a=10;
      now i want to use value of 'a' in jsp tag like

```
 <% int b= "how to store javascript variable here"

  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the javascript variable value in a hidden field before submit/process it in server side, so it will be sent as part of Request parameters

```
document.getElementById('myHidden').value=myVariable;
```

To access the javascript variable in server side code

```
Request.getParameter("hiddenName")
```

Comment: i want the opposite one like, i want to store javascript variable in jsp variable Eg: int jspvariable= "java script variable"    how to do ?? its veryy urgent

Answer (score -1):

That's not possible. You need to read up on the difference between client-side and server-side. This is a really good post:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: so do you know how to accomplish that ??? Its veryy urgent and important ....

Comment: Like I said, you can't do that. The `int b` has already been processed on the server, the only way you can get that javascript variable into the JSP page is to return it back to the server, either via querystring or form post. To explain the entire process would be out of the scope of a stack overflow answer.